# Networkx add_node seems to ignore attributes parsed as dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, networkx

I'm tyring to load data from a social platform API into a networkx graph to conduct some analysis. But having issues. The `add_node` function seems to be ingoring the  I pass it and so no attributes are added.

**Data from the API**
comes in the form of:

```
data= {'users': [{'1': {'attrib1': 'some value',
                        'attrib2': 'some other value',
                     .... etc},
                  '2': {'attrib1': 'some val',
                        'attrib2': 'you get the idea',
                     ... etc},
                ... etc
                 }]}
```

so that's

```
dict with one key 'users'
     list with one element [0]
           a dict of each users with user number as the key
                 a dict that contains the same id and a load of other attributes
```

(slightly weird structure imo...)

I've been successful creating nodes in a `nx.DiGraph` with:

```
    G = nx.DiGraph()
    for u in data['users'][0].values():
         G.add_node(str(u['id']),attr_dict=u)
```

But when I quiz nodes in `G` (e.g. `nx.get_node_attibutes(G,'firstName')`) there doesn't seem to be any attributes attached to the nodes.

**Questions**

1. Is there something I'm doing wrong? The `u` in the loop is definitely a dict, I have checked.
2. Is there a more sane way of doing this? Perhaps by manipulating the `data` dict into a different structure?

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that you made a typo in `attr_dict`. It probably worked fine at your first try already, you just "quizzed the nodes" not very exhaustively, and thus did not realize what your typo was.

Instead of using `nx.get_node_attibutes(G,'firstName')` -- i.e. checking for a certain attribute to exist -- you could have used `G.node`, which lists all nodes in the graph as well as their attributes.

But let's get to the point. The deal about `add_node` is that if you add a node, you can pass attributes and their values as keyword-argument pairs. Take for example this code snippet right from the `add_node` documentation page:

```
G.add_node(3,weight=0.4,UTM=('13S',382871,3972649))
```

Here we add a node with id `3` to the graph and give it a `weight` attribute with a value of `0.4` and a `UTM` attribute with a tuple as value. If we check it with `G.node` we see

```
>>> G.node
{3: {'weight': 0.4, 'UTM': ('13S', 382871, 3972649)}}
```

Every keyword is added as a `key` in the node's attribute dict!
It all went well. This is exactly the same outcome as if we had passed the attributes as an `attr_dict`:

```
>>> G.clear()
>>> G.add_node(3, attr_dict={'weight': 0.4, 'UTM': ('13S',382871,3972649)})
>>> G.node
{3: {'weight': 0.4, 'UTM': ('13S', 382871, 3972649)}}
```

In your case I suspect that you made a typo in "attr_dict". In this case, networkx thought that instead of meaning the actual `attr_dict` keyword you meant a attribute name. Here's an example:

```
>>> G.clear()
>>> G.add_node(3, attr_dict_typo={'weight': 0.4, 'UTM': ('13S',382871,3972649)})
>>> G.node
{3: {'attr_dict_typo': {'weight': 0.4, 'UTM': ('13S', 382871, 3972649)}}}
```

So when you tried to check the if the attribute `'firstname'` existed with `nx.get_node_attibutes(G,'firstName')`, the function looked for a key named `'firstname'`, but only found `'attr_dict_typo'`, and returned `None`.

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 1):

As of the [v2.0 release](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/release/release_2.0.html) of `networkx`, the `attr_dict` parameter is not allowed anymore in the `.add_edge()` and `add_edges_from()` methods. Perhaps this has been also propagated to `add_node()` as well.

Perhaps you can try adding them by using: `G.add_node(1, **attr_dict)`

See also the relevant issue in GitHub: 
https://github.com/networkx/networkx/pull/2107

Answer (score 0):

OK, in a moment of desperation I removed the keyword argument `attr_dict` from the `add_node` call. e.g.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
for u in data['users'][0].values():
     G.add_node(str(u['id']),u)
```

and it worked! I have no idea why it didn't like me explicitly mapping the argument. Anyone have any idea why?

I'm intrigued.